# How to disable Xcode warning "Enable Base Internationalization"?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, warnings, compiler-warnings

This warning started to appear on Xcode 10 Beta 6.

I perfectly understand its meaning, yet I wish to disable it. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 12):

I managed to get rid of the warning by turning off "Missing Localizability" in the build settings.

[image]

This prevents the warning from reappearing if you turn off base internationalization.

To remove the initial warning i had to restart xcode with base internationalization turned on. Once the warning is gone you can disable base internationalization again. And be happy because there is one less warning in your project. (or very happy if there are none)

Comment: You've made my day. Very very happy with no warnings :)

Comment: As you wrote, I needed to restart Xcode after turning off the stated switches in "build" (under project target). Not at all obvious - thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The warning will go away if you edit your `project.pbxproj` (inside of your `xcodeproj`) with an editor and add `Base` to the `knownRegions` key.

Not sure if it has any side effects though.

```
knownRegions = (
    en,
    nl,
    Base,
);
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as clicking "**Enable**" from the prompt opening from the Xcode warning.

Comment: @Cœur When you click on the warning you get the "Choose files and reference language" dialog. If you don't have any resource files you can still click on Finish, but nothing will happen. The warning will be gone until you close and re-open Xcode. My only option in this case was to manually edit the pbxproj file.

Comment: oh, didn't know about the scenario without any resource files. I gave you my upvote.

Answer (score -7):

You need to open all XIB or storyboard. Check localization table. If it is a space, you need to choose a localization language.